# Split a large file into smaller files using awk with numeric suffix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, split, aix

I am using AIX where split does not has "-d" flag, which will add numbering suffix to the smaller files after splitting.

My only option to do this in one-liner would be using AWK.

I have a large file "main.txt", i want them split and have 2-digit numeric suffix:

What I am able to do :

```
$ split -l 10 main.txt main_
main_a
main_b
main_c
```

What i want is :

```
main_01
main_02
main_03
```

Comment: Which shell are you running ?

Comment: i using korn shell "-ksh"

Comment: Is perl installed on AIX by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '(NR%10) == 1{close(out); out=sprintf("main_%02d",++c)} {print > out}' file
```

or to use your input file name as the base for the output files:

```
awk '
    NR==1 { base=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",base) }
    (NR%10) == 1 { close(out); out=sprintf("%s_%02d",base,++c) }
    { print > out }
' file
```

Comment: Thanks. I was about to follow up with this question but you already answered. :)